# Query printer status on my d-link print server

Tags: c#, snmp

I have an d-link dp-311p print server which provides the printer status(offline, paper out, etc) on it's interface.
How can i get this oid status ?? i'm trying to find through axence nettools but there is A LOT of keys and the descriptions are not friendly...
Also, i'm trying to use [this](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/blog/archive/2005/08/08/182.aspx) code(c#) to access the print server status but no success...
please, need a light, i'm completely lost!
Tks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it! Here is how:
Search for mib browser because I didn't know the oid of the print server status. Found [This one](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml), then, I created a console app like this

```
OLEPRNLib.SNMP snmp = new OLEPRNLib.SNMP();
int Retries = 1;
int TimeoutInMS = 2000;
string CommunityString = "public";
string IPAddressOfPrinter = "192.168.1.12";
string ALLINEED;

// Open the SNMP connect to the print server
snmp.Open(IPAddressOfPrinter, CommunityString, Retries, TimeoutInMS);
ALLINEED = snmp.Get(".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.1.1.3.0");
snmp.Close();

Console.Write(ALLINEED);
```

On my machine I made a reference on the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog to “oleprn 1.0 Type Library“ which lived in “c:\Windows\System32\oleprn.dll“

Hope this can help someone.

Tks

Comment: Good job! You should be able to mark this as the answer then.